# Getting values from previous rows using user-defined variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, user-defined

I have a table named as "t1", my table is-

```
+------+------+
| c1   |  c2  |
+------+------+
|  1   |   12 |
|  2   |   13 |
|  3   |   14 |
+------+------+
```

I want to get all rows along with the previous values of col2.
The query I use:-

```
Select c1,@prev,@prev:=c2 from t1;
```

I get following output-

```
+------+---------+------------+
| c1   |  @prev  | @prev:=c2  |
+------+---------+------------+
|  1   |   NULL  |    12      |
|  2   |   NULL  |    13      |
|  3   |   NULL  |    14      |
+------+---------+------------+
```

I was expecting to get only NULL in the first row. But I am getting NULL in all rows.
Please explain why it's giving NULL in all rows.

Comment: [Note](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html): "Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL." If you're on MySQL 8.0+, `SELECT c1, LAG(c2) OVER() AS c2 FROM t1;` is both way more legible, and also future-proof.

Comment: Ya, it work but my doubt is only how I am getting NULL in rows.

Comment: @T.g - The behavior is just undefined and depends on the used version and it's engine/optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the NULLs is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> Another issue with assigning a value to a variable and reading the
> value within the same non-SET statement is that the default result
> type of a variable is based on its type at the start of the statement.

Since `@prev` is not defined before it is read for the first time, we cannot even say, what type it has.

Now you could preset it to some value like `set @prev = 0;`. But `0` might be a valid value, so you probably want it to be NULL for the first row. `set @prev = null;` will neither work. But you can do the following:

```
set @prev = -1;   -- define type as SIGNED
set @prev = null; -- set NULL
```

Now you query should return

```
c1  @prev   @prev:=c2
1   null    12
2   12      13
3   13      14
```

You can also define the type and assign NULL in a single statement:

```
set @prev = cast(null as signed);
```

See [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6wS5FrFmpkyy8BHBzPvSni/0)

However - When you read and write a user variable in the same statement (other than SET) - the behavior is not defined. In the documentation you will find the following statements:

> It is also possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements
> other than `SET`. (This functionality **is deprecated** in *MySQL 8.0* and
> subject to removal in a subsequent release.)

> ...

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, **you should never**
> assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
> statement.

> ...

> For other statements, such as `SELECT`, you might get the results you
> expect, but this is **not guaranteed**.

I've marked the important parts in bold, so you can see that it's not recommended to use the variables in that way.

Newer versions (MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2) now support [window functions like `LEAD()` and `LAG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag). So you can write the query the following way:

```
Select c1, c2, lag(c2) over (order by c1) as prev
from t1
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fUUjy6dMvBpF93tADKFy14/0)

This is not only reliable for future MySQL versions. It will also work on many (all major) RDBM-systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8acba56897d8547b0fe7a3fc2d699693)**

```
SET @prev=-1;
Select c1,@prev prev_col,@prev:=c2 cur_col
from t1 order by c1
```

OUTPUT:

```
c1  prev_col    cur_col
1     -1          12
2     12          13
3     13          14
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting all `NULL` values is because you aren't initialising your `@prev` variable. You can initialise it with a `SET @prev := 0` statement or, if you need to get this result with only a single query, you can use a `CROSS JOIN` to initialise your variable:

```
SELECT c1, @prev AS prev, @prev:=c2 AS c2
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev := 0) v;
```

Output:

```
c1  prev    c2
1   0       12
2   12      13
3   13      14
```

If you don't *have* to use a variable, and your `c1` values are consecutive, you can also get the same result using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c2 AS prev
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 t2 ON t2.c1 = t1.c1 - 1
ORDER BY t1.c1
```

If your `c1` values might not be consecutive, the above `LEFT JOIN` won't work properly. In that case you need to `JOIN` on the value of `c1` which is the highest value less than the value to be `JOIN`ed to:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c2 AS prev
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 t2 ON t2.c1 = (SELECT MAX(c1) 
                            FROM t1 t3 
                            WHERE t3.c1 < t1.c1)
ORDER BY t1.c1
```

In both cases the output is the same:

```
c1  c2  prev
1   12  null
2   13  12
3   14  13
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/741ktBKGF1aH6UCki1VKbA/1)

Comment: Note that the second snippet will do something very different if the values in `c1` are not contiguous.

Comment: @Amadan you are absolutely correct, thanks for pointing it out. I've made a note about that and added a query that will work in that scenario too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous value with a subquery:

```
    SET @def = 0;

    Select 
      t.c1,
      coalesce(
        (select c2 from tablename where c1 < t.c1 order by c1 desc limit 1), 
        @def) prev_col,
      t.c2 cur_col
    from tablename t order by t.c1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/91fuVYotci2xtw4LMgJh7C/0)
Or:

```
SET @def = 0;

Select 
  t.c1,
  coalesce(
    (select max(c2) from tablename where c1 < t.c1), 
    @def) prev_col,
  t.c2 cur_col
from tablename t order by t.c1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/91fuVYotci2xtw4LMgJh7C/1)